# Read title of CSV's from a folder path , and write the header rows to another csv with structure as Table Name and Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Issue: I have two CSV files names File1.CSV and File2.CSV in one folder where the structure of the csv is like

```
File1.csv
Column1 Column2
Data.    Data.

File2.csv
Column3 Column4
```

The final file .csv structure should look like this:

```
Table Name.    Column Names
File1.           Column1
File1.           Column2
File2            Column3
File2            Column4
```

I have written something like this

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list1 = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    list1.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(frame)
```

Kindly suggest I want to write this into a new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce the final version as you expected, you may need a result dataframe and a temporary formatted dataframe for each file then, concatenate them together in every single loop.

The following code yields what you need:

```py
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Table Name", "Column Names"])

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    formatted_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Table Name": [filename] * len(columns), "Column Names": columns})

    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, formatted_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

result_df.to_csv("final_file.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

| index | Table Name | Column Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | File1.csv | col1 |
| 1 | File1.csv | col2 |
| 2 | File2.csv | col3 |
| 3 | File2.csv | col4 |

Hope this helps!